# Show only a single axis of a chart (for trellis charts)

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm building a [trellis chart](http://trellischarts.com/what-is-a-trellis-chart) in SSRS, using a matrix with a chart object inside it.

To keep the chart tidy (I've set it so that every axis has the same range of values in it using `Align Axes in:`) I want to remove the axes from the charts, and instead have a single instance of the Y axis in the left most column of each row, and single instance of the X axis in the foot of each column.

I've been attempting to do this by placing copies of the chart in those locations, but I can't figure out how to remove everything but the axis.

I'm looking for how to do one of two solutions:

- Find a way to hide or remove all chart elements except the axis
- Stop the chart from resizing with the cell so I can hide the unwanted elements by adjusting the cell size

Comment: While I wasn't able to do this with the Y axis I was able to do it with the X axis by clicking the chart area and setting the Custom Inner Plot height to 1, then deleting the y axis and colouring the series white

Comment: I've done this previously with setting the existence/ visibility of the axis components set to be dependent on the group the chart appears in